# Xcode view with two CollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a story board which I have added two collection views. I dragged the elements to my .h files and made outlets. I have created the initial methods for both of the collection views which means I have for example :

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection(NSInteger)section
```

And I also created another similar method for my second collectionview:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView2(UICollectionView *)collectionView2 numberOfItemsInSection(NSInteger)section
```

but the problem is when I log which methods are called methods of second collection view are never called.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second delegate method is never called because it is not a delegate method of the `UICollectionView`

`UICollectionView` view always call the first method because it comforts to it's dataSource delegate protocol.

Please take a look at the delegate method itself:
`-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection(NSInteger)section`

And you will notice that the delegate is passing you the `(UICollectionView *)collectionView` that it wants to know this specific collection view's numbers of items in section ;-)

All you have to do is to query what collection view it passed to you

```
if(collectionView == myCollectionView1)
{
//    do stuff for collection view 1
}
else if(collectionView == myCollectionView2)
{
//    do stuff for collection view 2
}
//etc..
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so where should I define the names myCollectionView1 and myCollectionView2 to later address them?

Comment: @m0j1 If you are using a `StoryBoard` just make an OUTlets of your collections and name it as myCollectionView1 or whatever you want :)

Comment: You can check out my github repo as well if you like: https://github.com/vnchopra/CustomCellTabledCollectionView

Answer (score 2):

When you link your two collection view's to their `datasource` and `delegate` properties via interface builder, they must conform to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocols.. If their delegate/datasource objects are the same thing then you must use the same method implementations in your class for both collection views.

You can do this by creating an IBOutlet for each collection view in your view controller, for example:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *primaryCollectionView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *secondaryCollectionView;
```

You can then check what collection view is the caller from the delegate methods when you receive the callbacks, for example:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection(NSInteger)section {

      if (collectionView == self.primaryCollectionView) {
           return 12;

      } else if (collectionView == self.secondaryCollectionView) {
           return 6;

      } else {
           return 0;
      }
 }
```